# KafkaMetrics - Failed to bind meter: kafka.consumer*

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, prometheus, kafka-consumer-api, micrometer

I have deployed an application as a container on OpenShift. The application consists of four threads (i.e. consumers) - each polling on a unique topic. I would like to display the KafkaMetrics for each of the consumers/topics. I have already sat up a functioning Prometheus endpoint.

Each of the consumers' metrics are bound to this Prometheus Registry by:

```
KafkaClientMetrics(consumer).bindTo(promRegistry)
```

Moreover, I have experienced incosistency of the displayed metrics at the Prometheus endpoint. For some metrics, data is displayed for only one of the consumers. I also get the following warnings in the OpenShift log:

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-09-06T12:45:43.608+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Failed to bind meter: 
kafka.consumer.fetch.manager.records.lag.max [tag(client.id=client2), tag(topic=my_topic), tag(partition=2), tag(kafka.version=6.2.0-ccs)].",
"logger_name":"io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics","thread_name":"micrometer-kafka-metrics","level":"WARN","level_value":30000,
"stack_trace":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Collector already registered that provides name: 
kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag_max\n\t
at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry.register(CollectorRegistry.java:54)\n\t
at io.prometheus.client.Collector.register(Collector.java:139)\n\t
at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.lambda$applyToCollector$16(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:410)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(Unknown Source)\n\t
at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.applyToCollector(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:406)\n\t
at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.newGauge(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:208)\n\t
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.lambda$gauge$1(MeterRegistry.java:298)\n\t
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.lambda$registerMeterIfNecessary$5(MeterRegistry.java:562)\n\t
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.getOrCreateMeter(MeterRegistry.java:620)\n\t
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.registerMeterIfNecessary(MeterRegistry.java:569)\n\t
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.registerMeterIfNecessary(MeterRegistry.java:562)\n\t
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.gauge(MeterRegistry.java:298)\n\t
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.Gauge$Builder.register(Gauge.java:190)\n\t
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics.registerGauge(KafkaMetrics.java:224)\n\t
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics.registerMeter(KafkaMetrics.java:216)\n\t
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics.bindMeter(KafkaMetrics.java:208)\n\
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics.lambda$checkAndBindMetrics$1(KafkaMetrics.java:191)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Unknown Source)\n\t
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics.checkAndBindMetrics(KafkaMetrics.java:161)\n\t
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics.lambda$bindTo$0(KafkaMetrics.java:112)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\n\t
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\n\t
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\n"}
```

These type warnings occur for the three conumers that does not display all the metrics.

Have anyone experienced this exception before?

I will happily provide more information or code if necessary, but as of now I do not know what code would be relevant to include.

Comment: I don't think you can publish the same metric name with a completely different set of tags (which would happen if you bind more than one consumer). You can make one consumer subscribe to multiple topics

Comment: The topics yield records with different types of values. Hence, it is necessary to create several customers with unique value deserializers. I think it would be quite a hassle to merge all the customers into one.

Comment: But the funny/ weird thing is that some metrics are shown for all the consumers and some metrics are only shown for the one consumer (i.e. the three other consumers lack these metrics).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem! When setting up the Promotheus endpoint, I also added two `common_tags` to the `promregistry`. It looks like these common tags were causing trouble for the default tags set by the consumer when binding to the `promregistry`. By removing the setting of the common tags, all metrics are displayed for all consumers.